# Regarding CSS Media Query

Tags: css

I made a website for mobile first but am really confused to add a seperate css for desktop version.

Should i just put all my code for max width-500px and write seperate CSS for desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you want to design your website we call it **MOBILE FIRST APPROACH**
So in this scenario what you can do, just create your website on mobile-first and write your all CSS code without any media query.

once you are done with mobile view, then change the things in media Query using `min-width` selector.

by this, you just need to change the CSS for your desktop version.

So your CSS code will look like this.

```
 All your css without any media query, what ever you need.
```

and then

```
 @media(min-width:480px){
    all your desktop changes will go here.
 }
```

so `min-width` media query will work above your selected breakpoint, in this case above 480px.

remember, you can take multiple media breakpoints, and 480 is also changeable, so change this point as per your need.

there are lots of tutorial and articles for it, you can check [this one.](https://blog.alexdevero.com/ultimate-guide-mobile-first-web-design/)

Comment: I am exactly doing this :) but the problem i have to repeat almost all code again

Comment: You don't have to wrap everything in a media query. You can set your background color and font size first and then only change the font size if the screen is big / small enough

Comment: So idea is same as joeri said above. You don't need to write all the properties again... For example if you set background color on mobile without media query then you don't need to touch this property in media query unless you don't want different background color or text colors on desktop. We usually change the order of the items, width, font sizes, and if you still having problem.. just put your code in a codepen or fiddle. And share..  I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing mobile first write your CSS for mobile and then use min width media queries while scaling up.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your desktop styles at the bottom, with the rule:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 425px) {
  /* css desktop rules */
}
```

425px as the minimum size in Chrome for desktop.
I recommend using a css style preprocessor (SASS, for example) to be able to nest rules and import styles into a separate file (`@import ...`).

Comment: wouldn't these be the mobile CSS rules? `max-device-width: 425px` means any device with a width of less than or equal to `425px`

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake. Edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches for this.

1. Use media queries in one file
2. Use different CSS sheets depending on device width
3. Use a style preprocessor like SASS or SCSS

Media query:

This will make the bgcolor change depending on screen height

```css
p {
  padding: 1em;
  background: #55f;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  p {
    background: #f55;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Switch to full page view to see this change</p>
```

Different style sheets

By adding some media queries to your `<link />` tags you can load different style sheets depending on screen size and whatnot

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1025px)" href="desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1024px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

CSS Prerpocessors

There are several great options regarding these. I am not well versed in them but I'd recommend doing some research and choosing the one you feel most comfortable with.